# HADOOP commands not working any where in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: hadoop

[image]

[image]

`Hadoop` commands not working any where 
commands working `hadoop/bin` directory only once abserve first I have tried outside `hadoop/bin` second time I had done with in bin

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make a soft link between `Hadoop` directory and your user `bin` directory. In this way you'll be able to call `Hadoop` command from everywhere.

So, to solve your issue, run this command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs /usr/local/bin/hdfs
```

I hope this could help you.

---

More info about `ln` command can be read in the manual with this command:

```
 man ln
```

Comment: i did above command but still not working

Comment: @NaveenReddy Sorry, it was my fault. You can try with the updated command. To remove previous link you can run this command:  `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/Hadoop`

Comment: help me to remove below created link             -------nvnhadoop@naveen-ubuntu:~$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/hadoop/bin /usr/local/bin
[sudo] password for nvnhadoop: 
nvnhadoop@naveen-ubuntu:~$

Comment: after executing above"edited" coomand below error is gettig -----nvnhadoop@naveen-ubuntu:~$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs /usr/local/bin/hdfs
[sudo] password for nvnhadoop: 
nvnhadoop@naveen-ubuntu:~$ hdfs dfs -ls /
/usr/local/bin/hdfs: line 35: /usr/local/bin/../libexec/hdfs-config.sh: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/hdfs: line 304: exec: : not found

Comment: nvnhadoop@naveen-ubuntu:~$ nano ~/.bashrc
Unable to create directory /home/nvnhadoop/.nano: Permission denied
It is required for saving/loading search history or cursor positions.

Press Enter to continue

nvnhadoop@naveen-ubuntu:~$ ls -al
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 12 17:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 May 10 23:45 ..
nvnhadoop@naveen-ubuntu:~$

Comment: nano ~/.bashrc not working with nvnhadoop(user) ---with naveen exported PATHS